# Excel VBA script to do data transition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report which has a list of Delegates and the products they signed up to.

[image: Report]

As you can see Nino Rossi signed up for 3 things: Conference and two workshops, where John Smith Signed up only for the conference. I would like to make a VBA script, which could help me to make a transition of the products like in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: The thing is, this is only the example. The report which I have will be generated regularly with different values. I manually removed additional names, where it won't work for next report. Therefore, it needs to identify records by itself

Comment: seems to me you want a paid consultant. Stack is for programming help, I.E. when you get stuck on a particular line of code or function. seems to me you're just looking for someone to code it for you.

Comment: Why would you want to change how it's setup? It's already in an ideal format for Excel to work with.  You could probably do this without VBA using a pivot table.  Either way, I would recommend *against* taking this action because it would make the data harder for Excel to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least you can use this function to return products separated by ", "

```
Function GetProducts(ByVal name As String, NameRange As Range) As String
Dim S As String, M, r As Long, Fadd
Set M = NameRange.Find(what:=name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
If M Is Nothing Then
 GetProducts = ""
Else
 S = M.Offset(0, 1).Value
 Fadd = M.Address
 Set M = NameRange.Find(what:=name, after:=M)
 Do While M.Address <> Fadd
  S = S & ", " & M.Offset(0, 1).Value
  Set M = NameRange.Find(what:=name, after:=M)
 Loop
 GetProducts = S
End If
End Function
```

First argument is the name you're looking for, second is the range that contains names, I am assuming that products are in the column just after names.